# Generating shuffle from given range with Java

Tags: android

```
 int start = 40;
 int end = 50;
 for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
 System.out.println(i);
```

Output:: 40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60

I know I ask a silly question

But I don't know how to shuffle this by collection.shuffle method
Please explain 
Experts

Comment: It would be better to read the [Collections documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) and try to write something on your own; if you encounter problems, post the code and explain difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself

Comment: Perhaps you should include the codes of how you use `Collections.shuffle()` and what problems or errors do you encounter

Comment: Dear sir i am read so many code from before 2 days and but i can't find how to use this method

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is:

```
List subList = arrayList.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
Collections.shuffle(subList);
```